# Python 3.4 How would I remove the extra line below TownName?

Tags: python, python-3.x

How would I remove the line below TownName() when I execute it?

```
def TownName():
    file = open('towns.txt','r')
    towns = file.readlines()
    towns = random.choice(towns)
    print(towns)
    file.close()

TownName()
```

[Image Proof](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SxIPx.jpg)

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that the lines you read via `file.readlines()` have a newline at the end, **and** that `print()` by default adds a newline when you call it.

You can either `strip()` the newlines from your lines, or you can tell `print` not to add a newline with `end=''` as an argument.

Comment: Note: Stripping is probably a better option, since some files will not end in a newline, and if you end up printing that final line without adding a newline, it won't feed to a new line. Specifically, you'd do `.rstrip("\r\n")` if the goal is only to eliminate the newlines, not other whitespace.

Answer (score 0):

In Python3, `print()` is a function. It contains a kwarg for the ending. By default, it is simply "\n".

```
print(towns, end="")
```

Usage:

```
print("Hello, ", end="")
print("World!") # this prints a newline after
# Hello, World!
#
```

Answer (score 0):

printing without newline, try this if you are using Python 3.x:

```
print(towns, end="")
```